# Why the push function repeat the objects in a array in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, duplicates

I am trying to build up a engine to control the physics of some custom rectangles in React. To achieve this, I created two classes the Body class which extends the "React.component" and the Engine class which has an array called "objectsInWorld" to keep their tracking.
The problem comes when I instantiate a body. This body receives the instance of the engine and call a engine's method "addBody" to include this body in the "objectsInWorld" but it duplicates they.
I attached the main code:

```
export default class Body extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    ...

    // add this body to the world controlled by the engine
    this.engine = props.engine;
    this.engine.addBody(this);
```

and the engine one:

```
export class Engine {
    constructor(props) {
        ...

        this.objectsInWorld = [];

        this.addBody = (body) => {
            console.log(this.objectsInWorld);
            this.objectsInWorld.push(body);
            console.log(this.objectsInWorld);
        }
    }
```

the outcome after create one square and one ground:

```
[Square] 
[Square, Square] 
[Square, Square, Ground]
[Square, Square, Ground, Ground]
```

I would appreciate any help (sorry if it's obvious) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution despite I don't understand clear why it wasn't working. The solution is to move the call "this.engine.addBody(this)" to the  componentDidMount() {} section instead of be in the constructor,

```
// start up the component
componentDidMount() {

     // add this body to the world controlled by the engine
     this.engine.addBody(this);
     console.log(this.engine.objectsInWorld);

}
```

Hope it helps anotherone.